# MySql Stored Procedure : Get Last Inserted Id

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

My Procedure :

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `******`.`*********************` 
(   IN customerName varchar(100),IN customerEmail varchar(100),IN address1 varchar(100),IN address2 varchar(100),
    IN zip int,IN city varchar(100),IN state varchar(100),IN country varchar(100),IN region varchar(100),OUT customerId int)
BEGIN

Declare custId int default 0;
Declare zipExist int default 0;

Select Count(*) into zipExist from *****.********** where Zip_Code = zip;

if zipExist = 0 then
Insert into *****.**********(Zip_Code,City,State,Country,Region) values(zip,city,state,country,region); 
end if;

Insert into *****.**********(Address_1,Address_2,ZIP_Code) values(address1,address2,zip);

SET custId = LAST_INSERT_ID();

if custId > 0 then
Insert into *****.**********(Customer_Name,Customer_Email,Address) values(customerName,customerEmail,custId);
end if;

SET customerId = LAST_INSERT_ID();
END $$
```

on calling the procedure I am getting this error:
Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

I am assuming that `custId= Last_Insert_Id();` this line is giving me wrong inserted id. hence it is not able to insert into last table.
I would like to know how to get  last inserted id after insert.(Address_id is auto-increment).

tables are :

**Customer:**
CustomerId int auto-increment,
CustomerName varchar,
CustomerEmail varchar,
AddressId int fk references address.AddressId

**Address :**

AddressId pk int auto-increment,
Address1 varchar,
Address2 varchar,
zip int fk references zipmaster.zip

**zipmaster :**

zip int pk auto-increment,
city varchar,
state varchar,
country varchar

Comment: Please format your code and share the table definition, You can also look at  [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and see what information should be provided with a question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. it's a little strange to redact (`*****`) the table names on your SQL queries.  I wonder if you have a mistake in this bit of SQL `Insert into Customer (Customer_Name, Customer_Email, Address)  values(customerName, customerEmail, custId);`  You don't have a column called `Address` in your Customer table. Should it be AddressId?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
LAST_INSERT_ID() returns only automatically generated AUTO_INCREMENT values, if the customer_id is not auto-increment you will not get the correct value.

For more information please refer the link :

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id
```